# Python 3x regular expression syntax

Tags: python, regex

While trying to remove  all repeating words in a string in an example below, what should be the correct syntax to check for 1 or more repetition of the word. The following example returns

```
cat cat in the hat hat hat
```

it ignores more than one repetition in the string, only removes "in" & "the" which have been repeated only once.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+) \1', r'\1', 'cat cat cat in in the the hat hat hat hat hat hat')
```

Comment: I'll keep racking my brain until someone else confirms, but my gut says regex isn't quite meant for this type of task. I've never been good at matching "dynamic repetition".

Answer (score 1):

This should print the given sentence with duplicates

```
check_for_repeats = 'cat cat cat in in the the hat hat hat hat hat hat'
words = check_for_repeats.split()
sentence_array = []

for i in enumerate(words[:-1]):
    if i[1] != words[i[0] + 1]:
        sentence_array.append(i[1])
if words[-1:] != words[-2:]:
    sentence_array.append(words[-1:][0])

sentence = ' '.join(sentence_array)
print(sentence)
```

Comment: I'm no Python master, but if I'm reading this correctly..wouldn't this replace `Hi, I am Sam. Sam I am.` with something like `Hi, am Sam. Sam am.`?  This could very well be doable and more efficient without regex, though.

Comment: Sweet, don't feel like looking into whether it works or not without being a Python man..but gave you a +1 for using a non-regex (and most likely more efficient) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [regex](http://regex101.com/r/kJ4kT1):

```
(\b[a-z]+)(?: \1)+
```

What I had to do is put your `\1` into a non-capturing group so that we could repeat it 1+ times.  Then we can replace it the same way you did:

```
re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+)(?: \1)', r'\1', 'cat cat cat in in the the hat hat hat hat hat hat')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+)(?: \1)+', r'\1', 'cat cat cat in in the the hat hat hat hat hat hat')
```

The repetition operator after the back-reference will make it match multiple repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+) (?=\1\b)', '', 'cat cat cat in in the the hat hat hat hat hat hat')
```

Answer (score 0):

A non regex alternative when order isn't important would be

```
" ".join(set(string_with_duplicates.split()))
```

This first splits the string by whitespace, turns the returned list into a set (which removes duplicates, as each element is unique), and then joins these items back into a string.

```
>>> string_with_duplicates = 'cat cat cat in in the the hat hat hat hat hat hat'
>>> " ".join(set(string_with_duplicates.split()))
'the in hat cat'
```

If the order of the words needs to be preserved, you could write something like this

```
>>> unique = []
>>> for w in string_of_duplicates.split():
        if not w in unique:
        unique.append(w)
>>> " ".join(unique)
'cat in the hat'
```